# How to Remove Visual C++ "Expand Menu" Arrow?

Tags: visual-c++, expand, mfc-feature-pack, submenu

When creating menus with submenus in Visual C++, I find that submenus begin as arrows that I must click to expand to see their contents. Is there a way (programmatically) to have the submenus pop-out already expanded (with no arrow to click)?

Here is an image of what I am talking about, before and after clicking aforementioned arrow: 
 [image: screen shot]
   [also here](http://www.postimage.org/image.php?v=Pq1qL6rr)

Comment: What UI library is that?!! Which operating system? I've never seen that on Windows before.

Comment: Uhm, it's in a Visual Studio 2008 MFC Application using ribbon menus. That's about all I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it seems you are using the MFC Feature Pack. 
Go to `CMainFrame::OnCreate()`, you should be able to find
something like

> `CMFCToolBar::SetBasicCommands(lstBasicCommands);`

somewhere inside it.

```
lstBasicCommands
```

is a list that holds all the menu items that are not be hidden initially.
Simple populate it with the items you like.

You may also want to check out the samples code available here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Samples\1033

In case you do not call SetBasicCommands and do not create the list, the expand button is removed. This releases you from enhancing the list everytime you add a new command.

Comment: Is there no way to simply set a flag or member to prevent this behavior instead of adding all the menu items to a list to not hide them?